# How can I include a database in my spigot plugin executable

Tags: mysql, sqlite, minecraft, bukkit

I've been searching for ages and I can't seem to find a way to have a database in my spigot plugin executable, so if someone can help that would be awesome.

preferred databases:
SQLite
MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You can't have (run) a database in your plugin executable. A database runs on a server and you can build up a connection to it. All SQL stuff is in the java.sql package.

You can run a database like your local minecraft server on your computer throw [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/).

Here is an example how you build up a connection to a local running database:

```java
Connection connection;
String host, port, username, password, databaseName;

host = "localhost"; // enter your host (ip address)
port = "3306"; // the entering port
username = "root"; // your username
password = ""; // your password
databaseName = "database-name"; // the database name, where you want to connect to

String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + databaseName;

try {
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
} catch (SQLException throwables) {
    throwables.printStackTrace();
}
```

I suggest you to create a SQL Class in which you manage all. Maby look for a tutorial on Youtube how to use SQL in Java.

Comment: i disagree because i made it work. i now have a db in my jar via shading